# VBA to import tables of variable lengths from several excel files into a main workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I receive periodical data from several excel files, always in the same format, and I need to import it to a main workbook (sheet called “Results”).

Previously, the several excel files only had 7 cells in the sheet to be imported and the code I had did the job. However, now the several excel files contain a table (A12:D) with a variable last row, and the table’s data needs to be imported. I tried to tweak the code and put autofilters there for importing, but nothing has worked.

The code below does:

1. Opens each file saved in specific location
2. Imports 7 specific cells with data into main spreadsheet – that’s the part that no longer applies
3. Closes the file and moves it to another location
4. Loops until all files in original location are imported in the main spreadsheet and files get moved to the end location

Please help in how step 2 could be changed so it imports a variable length table from row 12 to the last row to the main workbook in spreadsheet “Results”?

Code:

```
   Dim sFile As String           
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         
   Dim lastRow As Long
   Dim PathStart As String
   Dim PathEnd As String

   'Prep
   PathStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER").Range("B9") & "\"
   PathEnd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER").Range("B10") & "\"
   
   lastRow = Sheets("Results").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
   
   If Not FileFolderExists(PathStart) Then
      MsgBox "Received folder does not exist"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   
   If Dir(PathStart & "*.*") = "" Then
        MsgBox "There are no files to import"
   End If
   
   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Results")
   
   'Step 1 – go the original folder
   sFile = Dir(PathStart & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""
      
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(PathStart & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Form")
      
      'Step 2 – import data
      With wsTarget
         .Range("A" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C6").Value
         .Range("B" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C8").Value
         .Range("C" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C10").Value
         .Range("D" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("B13").Value
         .Range("E" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C13").Value
         .Range("F" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("D13").Value
         .Range("G" & lastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("E13").Value
         
         'source filename in the last column
         .Range("H" & lastRow).Value = Mid(sFile, 1, InStr(1, sFile, ".") - 1)
      End With
      
      'Step 3-4 – move file and go to next
      wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
      Name PathStart & sFile As PathEnd & sFile
      lastRow = lastRow + 1
      sFile = Dir() 
   Loop
   
errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
```

Thank you

One of attempts tried without luck were to put a filter for each of the files to be imported, and then only import the used rows into the main spreadsheet, but didn't succed:

```
wsSource.Range("A11").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
wsSource.Range("A12" & ":" & "A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Copy
    wsTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: _contain a table (A12:D)_ Is this a "table" ie [ListObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) with a named range ? If it is you can use the [.Range property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.range).

Comment: No, it is not a table or a named range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

    Const FORM = "FORM" ' sheet with data on

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet, rngTarget As Range
    Dim PathStart As String, PathEnd As String, sFile As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    ' Prep
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsMaster = .Sheets("MASTER")
        Set wsTarget = .Sheets("Results")
    End With
        
    With wsMaster
        PathStart = .Range("B9") & "\"
        PathEnd = .Range("B10") & "\"
    End With
   
    Dim fso As Object, oFolder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(PathStart) Then
        MsgBox "ERROR - folder PathStart does not exist", vbCritical, PathStart
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not fso.FolderExists(PathEnd) Then
        MsgBox "ERROR - folder PathEnd does not exist", vbCritical, PathEnd
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' go the original folder
    sFile = Dir(PathStart & "*.xls*")
    If sFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "ERROR - no files to import", vbCritical, PathStart
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With wsTarget
        lastrow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
        Set rngTarget = .Cells(lastrow, "A")
        MsgBox "Import starts at row " & rngTarget.Row, vbInformation
    End With
       
    ' open each files
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do Until sFile = ""
      
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(PathStart & sFile)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(FORM)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If wsSource Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "ERROR - no sheet Form in " & sFile, vbExclamation, PathStart
        Else
             With wsSource
                ' table at A12:D?
                r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If r >= 12 Then
                     i = r - 11
                     rngTarget.Resize(i, 4).Value2 = .Range("A12:D" & r).Value2
                     
                     'source filename in the column H
                     rngTarget.Offset(, 7).Value = fso.getBaseName(sFile)
                     
                     ' next file
                     Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(i)
                     n = n + 1
                End If
                
            End With
        End If
        wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wsSource = Nothing
      
        'move file and go to next
        Name PathStart & sFile As PathEnd & sFile
        sFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox n & " tables imported", vbInformation
End Sub
```